# Should I move a parameter check from my controller to my model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, nomethoderror, update-attributes

I have a belongs_to relationship that can be removed without destroying either the parent or the child (transfer_form). Users can eliminate the parent relationship by selecting the blank option in a select dropdown while editing. Unfortunately, when they do this, I end up with

NoMethodError: undefined method `id' for "":String

Unless I perform a check on my parameters.

The following works but smells bad. Is it possible to move my current_school check to my model? Is this something I should do or should I leave it in my controller?

```
def update
  @transfer_form = TransferForm.find(params[:id])

  t = params[:transfer_form]
  if t['current_school'] == ""
    t['current_school'] = nil
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    if @transfer_form.update_attributes(t)
  ...
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always just do

```
params['current_school'] = nil if params['current_school'].blank?
```

but in reality the best practice would be to validate it in your model and do something like:

```
validates :current_school, :allow_blank => false
```

Then when you save it with an empty string it will error out, but I'm guessing you just want to set it to nil.

**Update**

I think its fine in your controller, but if you really want it in your model I would just use a before_save callback, that way you don't have any code in your controller, it will just automatically set every empty string to nil:

```
(untested)

before_save :sanitize_school

def sanitize_school
  current_school = nil if current_school.blank? 
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Although cleaner than what I have it still remains in the model. As the relation is 0..n validation isn't possible and since I have other 0..n relations, I'd like to move it to my model if possible. Thank you for your answer though.

Comment: ...comment above should have read "...still remains in the controller."

Comment: Thanks for the code. I considered a before callback but for some reason it's not getting triggered before the update (or I'm interpreting it incorrectly). Using Mongoid so I can't say for certain...the callback should work. Anyway, to me your solution is the correct one.